# Thinking Sphinx : Relevance - infix vs. complete word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Using Thinking Sphinx in my rails app, I set it up to allow partial match with `infix` (for example, searching for "tray" would match "ashtray").

However, I'd like complete word match to have more weight (relevance) than infix match.

So, if my search for 'tray' returns these 3 results : "Silver Tray", "Ashtray" and "Some other tray" - I want the "Ashtray" to be the last result when sorting by relevance.

Is there a way to configure Sphinx to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own ranker. Here's how the default ones look like:

```
SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY_BM25 = sum(lcs*user_weight)*1000+bm25

SPH_RANK_BM25 = bm25

SPH_RANK_NONE = 1

SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT = sum(hit_count*user_weight)

SPH_RANK_PROXIMITY = sum(lcs*user_weight)

SPH_RANK_MATCHANY = sum((word_count+(lcs-1)*max_lcs)*user_weight)

SPH_RANK_FIELDMASK = field_mask

SPH_RANK_SPH04 = sum((4*lcs+2*(min_hit_pos==1)+exact_hit)*user_weight)*1000+bm25
```

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/weighting.html

Comment: Great ! Looks like the right direction tos earch for a solution. Now I *just* have to get how to set the ranker ;-D